# github Committing

Tags: github, commit

I have got github ssh details to get the client project, i never worked on github before. So sorry for this stupid question. I Have ssh keys(public,private which was generated under filezila from my system - ubuntu 10.04) and client has added those keys into his repos. And he has given commiting url from github to my system.

I have installed and made a test project under my account in github with the ubuntu system. But not able to commit the client work.

His url is somthing like this,

```
ssh://git@domain.com:/home/git/project.git
```

how can i commit this project files,

i guess i have to add those ssh private,public keys under this github installation but i dont know how to add. Please help me.

Comment: Are you talking about git, the VCS, or github, the website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add an SSH key to your github account, see their [help page](http://github.com/guides/providing-your-ssh-key) for more information. Make sure to test that it's been set up properly.
2. Ask your friend to add you as a collaborator to the project: Project page -> Admin -> Collaborators.
3. Clone the repo at home and have fun committing! The URL will look something like this:

   ```
   git@github.com:USERNAME/PROJECTNAME.git
   ```

   So example on linux:

   ```
   git clone git@github.com:USERNAME/PROJECTNAME.git
   ```

Comment: Thank you @Ward. Let me try it out.